# Unable to install on a Centos 6 the library "libsrtp"

Tags: linux, centos, installation, library

I try to install on a Centos 6 the library "libsrtp"  but it expects the below libraries already present under these paths /lib64 and /usr/lib64. 
could you please tell me how can I resolve this problem ?

```
error: Failed dependencies:
libc.so.6 is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libm.so.6 is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libpthread.so.0 is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libsrtp-1.4.4-10.20101004cvs.el7.i686
```

Comment: `i686` - you need the 32bit versions of those libraries.

Comment: You're installing an RPM for CentOS 7.. On CentOS 6.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

A libsrtp package is available in the EPEL repository. EPEL is "extra packages for enterprise Linux."

First ensure that the CentOS Extras repository is enabled. (It is enabled by default.)

Use yum to install the epel repository:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Then use yum to install libsrtp from the EPEL repo.

```
yum install libsrtp
```

This method is the safest way to resolve all of the package's dependencies and ensure you will get a version that works with CentOS 6.

Comment: Perfect answer but after the installtion I still got this  Error: Package: asterisk-core-11.20.0-1_centos6.x86_64 (ict)
           Requires: libsrtp.so.0()(64bit)

Comment: Could you include whether you are running x86_64 or i686 CentOS?

Comment: I am running: CentOS release 6.8 (Final) (x86_64)

Comment: I suspect the asterisk install you are using wasn't designed to live on CentOS 6.8. The libsrtp package should have created a symlink `/usr/lib64/libsrtp.so.1 -> libsrtp.so.1.0.0`. You could try creating another symlink `/usr/lib64/libsrtp.so.0 -> libsrtp.so.1.0.0` to trick asterisk into finding the library, but I suspect you've entered dependency hell. :-)

Comment: done with no success

Comment: I think asterisk-core library asks for a libsrtp library with a SONAME as libsrtp.so.0 and the current SONAME installed by YUM is libsrtp.so.1

Comment: solved :-)) with asterisk repo i installed the right libsrtp.so.0 with SONAME libsrtp.so.0 :-)))))))